# dynamic use of jq json for http request

Tags: json, bash, jq, influxdb, telegraf

I have been trying to find a way to make sure I can pass the key and values of this json in this link dynamically into influxDB.  I have the batch file that is below :

The json file is below from that link :

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "WBAD": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Workbasket Admin"
  },
  "WBCA": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Workbasket CreateAppWait"
  },
  "WBDE": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Workbasket default@"
  },
  "WBEW": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Workbasket eFormWriteFailure"
  },
  "WBFB": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Workbasket BackgroundProcessing"
  },
  "WBIC": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Workbasket IncompleteConnections"
  },
  "WBLB": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "17",
    "minDateTime": "23/12/2022 14:50",
    "description": "Workbasket LRBackgroundProcess"
  },
  "AEWB": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Assignment errors for Assign-WorkBasket"
  },
  "AEWL": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Assignment errors for Assign-Worklist"
  },
  "FEWB": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Flow errors for Assign-WorkBasket"
  },
  "FEWL": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Flow errors for Assign-Worklist"
  },
  "BQBP": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Broken queue System-Queue-BackgroundProcess"
  },
  "BQDE": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Broken queue System-Queue-DefaultEntry"
  },
  "CQCA": {
    "status": "UP",
    "count": "0",
    "minDateTime": "",
    "description": "Custom query Create App Requests"
  },
  "JS02": {
    "status": "UP",
    "description": "Job Scheduler CaseDocumentDeletion (Any one associated node:BackgroundProcessing)"
  },
  "JS04": {
    "status": "UP",
    "description": "Job Scheduler PurgeOldSIDExchangeRecords (All associated nodes:BackgroundProcessing)"
  },
  "JS01": {
    "status": "UP",
    "description": "Job Scheduler UpdateReferenceData (Any one associated node:BackgroundProcessing)"

}
```

The batch file :

```
 #!/bin/bash  
## GET  STATUS
WBLB_STATUS=`curl -s http://example:8080/Cluster | jq -r '.WBLB.status'`

WBCA_STATUS=`curl -s http://example:8080/Cluster | jq -r '.WBCA.status'`
       
if [ "$WBLB_STATUS" = "UP" ]; then
    echo "app_custom,wblb_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1"

elif [ "$WBLB_STATUS" = "DOWN" ]; then
    echo "app_custom,wblb_status="DOWN" wblb_status_code=0"
    
fi    
exit
```

The output is

```
app_custom,wblb_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
```

I do not want to each key with if but would like to have the output like this below

```
app_custom,app_wblb_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,app_wblc_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,app_wbad_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
......
```

I would want to use this to pass to the influx DB using this conf :

```
[[inputs.exec]]
  commands = ["/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/app_test.sh"]
  data_format = "influx"
  timeout = "30s"
  interval = "2m"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_entries` to split up the items into an array of key-value pairs, then [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29) to piece together the output strings:

```bash
curl -s http://example:8080/Cluster | jq -r '
  to_entries[] | select(.value | type == "object")
  | [.key, .value.status] as [$id, $status]
  | "app_custom,\($id | ascii_downcase)_status=\($status) wlb_status_code=\(["DOWN","UP"] | index($status))"
'
```

```
app_custom,wbad_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wbca_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wbde_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wbew_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wbfb_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wbic_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wblb_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,aewb_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,aewl_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,fewb_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,fewl_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,bqbp_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,bqde_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,cqca_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,js02_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,js04_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,js01_status=UP wlb_status_code=1
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/86VSq6PABuh)

Comment: Thanks alot.  I added ["DOWN","UP", null, ""]  amd it also automatically added all to the influxDB for me.

Comment: suppose I want the key and value to all be in one line rather than each one in each line. Is this possible also eg  like this app_custom,wbad_status=UP wlb_status_code=1, app_custom,wbca_status=UP wlb_status_code=1, app_custom,wbde_status=UP wlb_status_code=1, app_custom,wbew_status=UP wlb_status_code=1, app_custom,wbfb_status=UP wlb_status_code=1, app_custom,wbic_status=UP wlb_status_code=1, app_custom,wblb_status=UP wlb_status_code=1, app_custom,aewb_status=UP wlb_status_code=1, app_custom,aewl_status=UP wlb_status_code=1,

Comment: @user5820327 Add a glue string, e.g. `, ` at the end of the string in the last line (before the last `"`), and change `jq -r` to `jq -j` (which acts as `-r` but without adding newlines to every item).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`to_entries` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) to transform your entries into a list of dictionaries with `key` and `value` members, and then you have a data structure that is much  easier to filter.

That is, running `jq to_entries data.json` (where `data.json` contains your sample data) produces output like:

```
[
  {
    "key": "status",
    "value": "UP"
  },
  {
    "key": "WBAD",
    "value": {
      "status": "UP",
      "count": "0",
      "minDateTime": "",
      "description": "Workbasket Admin"
    }
  },
  ...
```

We can extract the keys and values we want from that, and then use the `@tsv` filter to generate output that's easier to work with in the shell. The following `jq` command line:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[]|select(.key != "status")|[.key, .value.status]|@tsv' data.json
```

Produces as output:

```
WBAD    UP
WBCA    UP
WBDE    UP
WBEW    UP
WBFB    UP
WBIC    UP
WBLB    UP
AEWB    UP
AEWL    UP
FEWB    UP
FEWL    UP
BQBP    UP
BQDE    UP
CQCA    UP
JS02    UP
JS04    UP
JS01    UP
```

We can read values using the `read` shell function:

```
#!/bin/bash

jq -r 'to_entries[]|select(.key != "status")|[.key, .value.status]|@tsv' data.json |
while read key status; do
    [[ $status = "UP" ]] && code=1 || code=0
    echo "app_custom,${key,,}_status=\"$status\" wlb_status_code=$code"
done
```

Which produces:

```
app_custom,wbad_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wbca_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wbde_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wbew_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wbfb_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wbic_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,wblb_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,aewb_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,aewl_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,fewb_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,fewl_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,bqbp_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,bqde_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,cqca_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,js02_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,js04_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
app_custom,js01_status="UP" wlb_status_code=1
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful, but I need it to call a http request and to choose from whatsoever the status. It seems you have only option UP here not the DOWN> But this is really good.

Comment: No, this handles both UP and DOWN status; your sample data happened to only include `UP`.

Comment: Yea, oh I see. you are not calling the http in the code.